# Node FFI wrapper function fails when used synchronously, but works asynchronously

Tags: c, node.js, asynchronous, rust, node-ffi

I'm trying to wrap a Rust library (that exposes a C API) with Node FFI. I have the following code wrapping two functions. One is a "constructor" that returns a pointer. The other takes a pointer and returns C string.

```
var libcomm = ffi.Library('lib/c_api/target/debug/libcomm', {
  'comm_address_for_content': ['pointer', ['string']],
  'comm_address_to_str': ['string', ['pointer']]
});
```

When I use the asynchronous invocation of `comm_address_to_str` the response is correct. However, when I try to call the function using the synchronous style, it returns garbage, or very very rarely, the correct result. The following nodeunit test exercises the scenario:

```
const comm = require("../").libcomm;

exports.testAddressForContent = function (test) {
  const ptr = comm.comm_address_for_content('test');

  const result = comm.comm_address_to_str(ptr);
  test.equal(result, 'a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3'); // always fails
  console.log('sync', result); // random garbage

  comm.comm_address_to_str.async(ptr, function(err, result) {
    test.equal(result, 'a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3'); // always passes
    console.log('async', result); // 'a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3'
    test.done();
  });
}
```

I can't figure out what causes this, but I need to be able to use the sync invocation style. The C API of the Rust library I am wrapping is [here](https://github.com/zacstewart/comm/blob/master/c_api/src/comm.rs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, I am afraid, comes from the `comm` library, and specifically the [`comm_address_to_str`](https://github.com/zacstewart/comm/blob/master/c_api/src/comm.rs#L45) function:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn comm_address_to_str(address: *const Address) -> *const c_char {
    let string = unsafe { *address }.to_str();
    CString::new(string).unwrap().as_ptr()
}
```

The [documentation of `CString::as_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.as_ptr) specifically calls out this pattern:

```
use std::ffi::{CString};

let ptr = CString::new("Hello").unwrap().as_ptr();
unsafe {
    // `ptr` is dangling
    *ptr;
}
```

The `CString` created on the last line is immediately destructed after taking a pointer into its internals, leading to a dangling pointer.

The `comm` library that you are using will need to be fixed, and it might be worth auditing the other functions as well.

The fix here would be to leak the `CString`, and then provide another function to be called with the leaked pointer which will take care of freeing it.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I should note that I am the author of this upstream `comm` library. It looks like using `std::mem::forget(string)` before returning the `const *char` pointing to it does indeed solve the problem.

Comment: @Zac: You're welcome :) I would note that normally you should leak the `CString` instance, not `string`. You might want to run your Rust tests under valgrind to spot those issues ahead of time.

Comment: See also [returning strings in the Rust FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/string_return/).

Comment: So, what do you think is the reason that introducing a thread allowed it to "work"?

Comment: @Shepmaster: Well, UB and all... but if I would have to take a shot I would bet on thread-local arenas. Freshly freed memory is hot in the cache, so it's the best memory to use for an allocation. In the synchronous case, it means re-using it immediately (corrupting it), whereas in the asynchronous case, if all the work is done on another thread, it'll be using another thread-local arena to allocate from which gives the freshly freed memory a bit more time.